# Parallel EF Core queries with DbContext injection in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have writing an ASP.NET Core web application that needs all the data from some tables of my database to later organize it into readable format for some analysis.

My problem is that this data is potentially massive, and so in order to increase performance i decided to get this data in parallel and not one table at a time.

My issue is that i dont quite understand how to achieve this with the inherit dependency injection as in order to be able to do parallel work, i need to instantiate the `DbContext` for each of these parallel work.

The below code produces this exception:

```
---> (Inner Exception #6) System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'MyDbContext'.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.CheckDisposed()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ChangeTracker()
```

***ASP.NET Core project:***

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

    services.AddDbContext<AmsdbaContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"))
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Controller's action method:

```
[HttpPost("[controller]/[action]")]
public ActionResult GenerateAllData()
{
    List<CardData> cardsData;

    using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
    using (var dataFetcher = new DataFetcher(scope))
    {
        cardsData = dataFetcher.GetAllData(); // Calling the method that invokes the method 'InitializeData' from below code
    }

    return something...;
}
```

***.NET Core Library project:***

DataFetcher's InitializeData - to get all table records according to some irrelevant parameters:

```
private void InitializeData()
{
    var tbl1task = GetTbl1FromDatabaseTask();
    var tbl2task = GetTbl2FromDatabaseTask();
    var tbl3task = GetTbl3FromDatabaseTask();

    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        tbl1task,
        tbl2task,
        tbl3task,
    };

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

    Tbl1 = tbl1task.Result;
    Tbl2 = tbl2task.Result;
    Tbl3 = tbl3task.Result;
}
```

DataFetcher's sample task:

```
private async Task<List<SomeData>> GetTbl1FromDatabaseTask()
{
    using (var amsdbaContext = _serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AmsdbaContext>())
    {
        amsdbaContext.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        return await amsdbaContext.StagingRule.Where(x => x.SectionId == _sectionId).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure you do actually need multiple contexts here. You have have noticed that in the EF Core docs, there's this conspicuous warning:

> **Warning**
>
> EF Core does not support multiple parallel operations being run on the same context instance. You should always wait for an operation to complete before beginning the next operation. This is typically done by using the `await` keyword on each asynchronous operation.

This is not entirely accurate, or rather, it's simply worded somewhat confusingly. You can actually run parallel queries on a single context instance. The issue comes in with EF's change tracking and object fixup. These types of things don't support multiple operations happening at the same time, as they need to have a stable state to work from when doing their work. However, that really just limits your ability to do certain things. For example, if you were to run parallel saves/select queries, the results could be garbled. You might not get back things that are actually there now or change tracking could get messed up while it's attempt to create the necessary insert/update statements, etc. However, if you're doing non-atomic queries, such as selects on independent tables as you wish to do here, there's no real issue, especially, if you're not planning on doing further operations like edits on the entities you're selecting out, and just planning on returning them to a view or something.

If you truly determine you need separate contexts, your best bet is new up your context with a using. I haven't actually tried this before, but you should be able to inject `DbContextOptions<AmsdbaContext>` into your class where these operations are happening. It should already be registered in the service collection since it's injected into your context when the service collection instantiates that. If not, you can always just build a new one:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder()
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .Build()
    .Options;
```

In either case, then:

```
List<Tbl1> tbl1data;
List<Tbl2> tbl2data;
List<Tbl3> tbl3data;

using (var tbl1Context = new AmsdbaContext(options))
using (var tbl2Context = new AmsdbaContext(options))
using (var tbl3Context = new AmsdbaContext(options))
{
    var tbl1task = tbl1Context.Tbl1.ToListAsync();
    var tbl2task = tbl2Context.Tbl2.ToListAsync();
    var tbl3task = tbl3Context.Tbl3.ToListAsync();

    tbl1data = await tbl1task;
    tbl2data = await tbl2task;
    tbl3data = await tbl3task;
}
```

It's better to use `await` to get the actual result. This way, you don't even need `WaitAll`/`WhenAll`/etc. and you're not blocking on the call to `Result`. Since tasks return hot, or already started, simply postponing calling await until each has been created is enough to buy you parallel processing.

Just be careful with this that you select everything you need within the usings. Now that EF Core supports lazy-loading, if you're using that, an attempt to access a reference or collection property that hasn't been loaded will trigger an `ObjectDisposedException`, since the context will be gone.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer, but  what if i need to make like 10-20 queries like ?
do i have to repeat the keyword using??

Comment: Can you elaborate on why using `await` is better than `WaitAll`/`WhenAll`? What about `WhenAny`? Also could using a single `DbContext` cause its tracking or caching to get corrupted in a way that would affect an upstream caller that later called `SaveChanges` after the parallel queries complete? If so I would say the warning is correct since the DbContext is scoped to the request by default, and your method making parallel queries can't guarantee what another method will or won't do with the same `DbContext` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is - you do not. You need an alternative way to generate dbcontext instances. The standard approach is to get the same instance on all requests for a DbContext in the same HttpRequest. You can possibly override ServiceLifetime, but that then changes the behavior of ALL requests.

- You can register a second DbContext (subclass, interface) with a different service lifetime. Even then you need to handle the creation manually as you need to call it once for every thread.
- You manaully create them.

Standard DI simply comes to an end here. It is QUITE lacking, even compared to older MS DI frameworks where you possibly could put up a separate processing class with an attribute to override creation.